# jQuery UI - Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

> 3. Add jQuery code that makes the task lists for both employees droppable areas. When the drop event occurs, the draggable should be added to the end of the
>      other tasks for the employee. Because the position of the draggable changes as it’s dragged, you’ll also need to set the top and left properties of the draggable to zero so it appears in the correct location within the droppable.

---

I'm having an issue properly getting the web application to use drag and drop. I have no idea what I need to be doing, as my instructor never really gave us any help with using the jQuery UI. Do I need do use get elements by ID or anything like that? I'm really struggling with this.

**HTML & JQUERY CODE**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Task Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".ui-state-default").draggable({cursor: "move",
                                              grid: [25, 34]});
            $("#employee1, #employee2").droppable({
                drop: function(evt, ui) {
                    $(".ui-state-default").html(ui.draggable.children()).appendTo(this);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h2>Task List by Employee</h2>
        <div id="left">
            <h3>Kelly</h3>
            <div id="employee1">
                <div class="ui-state-default"><p>Manage office personnel</p></div>
                <div class="ui-state-default"><p>Process payables</p></div>                         
                <div class="ui-state-default"><p>Process payroll</p></div>                  
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="add1" value="Add Task">
       </div>
       <div id="right">
            <h3>Juliette</h3>
            <div id="employee2" class="connectedSortable">
                <div class="ui-state-default"><p>Enter orders</p></div>                     
                <div class="ui-state-default"><p>Process invoices</p></div>     
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="add2" value="Add Task">
        </div>       
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can't get the jsfiddle to work properly with the jquery ui

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle, that works with jQuery UI (add to external resources): https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fx2jjcbq/

Comment: @SamanthaCook remember that this site is public, so if your instructor searches, he might find your post. That said, the instructions are a little vague, as you mentioned. Looks like you have most of it so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the task into 3 steps:

1. Add jQuery code that makes the task lists for both employees droppable areas.
2. When the drop event occurs, the draggable should be added to the end of the other tasks for the employee.
3. Because the position of the draggable changes as it’s dragged, you’ll also need to set the top and left properties of the draggable to zero so it appears in the correct location within the droppable.

It worded in a way to throw you off and also to challenge students to think around the problem.

Working Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fx2jjcbq/3/

**HTML**

```
<main>
  <h2>Task List by Employee</h2>
  <div id="left">
    <h3>Kelly</h3>
    <div id="employee1" class="taskList">
      <div class="ui-state-default">
        <p>Manage office personnel</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-state-default">
        <p>Process payables</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-state-default">
        <p>Process payroll</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add1" value="Add Task">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h3>Juliette</h3>
    <div id="employee2" class="taskList">
      <div class="ui-state-default">
        <p>Enter orders</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-state-default">
        <p>Process invoices</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add2" value="Add Task">
  </div>
</main>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ui-state-default").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    grid: [25, 34]
  });

  $(".taskList").droppable({
    drop: function(evt, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      });
      $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

You can see I've added `taskList` as a class to each `div` that contains a list of tasks. This simply makes it easier to select the two lists. Now I can initialize both with the same block of `.droppable()` code, fulfilling step 1.

In the `drop` callback function, we need to use `.append()`, By default, this will add the element as the last child element.

> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

This addresses step 2.

For the final step, we want to use `.css()` to reset the `top` and `left` back to `0`. It has both a GET and SET method. We will use the set method.

> **Description:** Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

We want to do this before we append it to the list. Most will try to do it after, and that can be done, yet in my mind, it makes more sense to do this before.

There is also another method. As was mentioned in the task, dragging an element changes the `top` and `left` of the element. This is done through the `style` attribute. You can effectively do the same as above with:

```
ui.draggable.attr("style", "");
```

Hope that makes it more clear and good luck with your class.